# Caling Class from for loop

Tags: c#, class, for-loop

I´m working with a Visual studio c# form
I have a class with the following properties:

```
string Name;
int NumberOfHitBoxes;
Point Hit1;
Point Hit2;
Point Hit3;
```

I have a mouseMove event that detects if the mouse is in the "hitbox" it works fine like this: ( in the else part ( p.Hit1.X ))

```
picture.MouseMove += (sender,  e) =>
                            {
                                var c = sender as PictureBox;
                                bool h=false;
                                if (null == c) return;
                                if (_dragging)
                                {
                                c.Top = e.Y + c.Top - _yPos;
                                c.Left = e.X + c.Left - _xPos;
                                }
                                else
                                {   
                                    if ((e.X>p.Hit1.X)&&(e.X<p.Hit1.X+hitw)&&(e.Y>p.Hit1.Y)&&(e.Y<p.Hit1.Y+hitw)){hitbox(c,p.Hit1.X,p.Hit1.Y,8);h=true;tb.Text = p.Type;hitok = p.Input1Point;}  
                                    if ((e.X>p.Hit2.X)&&(e.X<p.Hit2.X+hitw)&&(e.Y>p.Hit2.Y)&&(e.Y<p.Hit2.Y+hitw)){hitbox(c,p.Hit2.X,p.Hit2.Y,8);h=true;tb.Text = p.Type;hitok = p.Input2Point;} 
                                    if ((e.X>p.Hit3.X)&&(e.X<p.Hit3.X+hitw)&&(e.Y>p.Hit3.Y)&&(e.Y<p.Hit3.Y+hitw)){hitbox(c,p.Hit3.X,p.Hit3.Y,8);h=true;tb.Text = p.Type;hitok = p.Output1Point;} 
                                }
                                if (!h){picture.Refresh();h=false;hitok = new Point(0,0);}
                            };
```

The number of hitboxex warry, so i want to do somthing like this:

```
picture.MouseMove += (sender,  e) =>
                            {
                                var c = sender as PictureBox;
                                bool h=false;
                                if (null == c) return;
                                if (_dragging)
                                {
                                c.Top = e.Y + c.Top - _yPos;
                                c.Left = e.X + c.Left - _xPos;
                                }
                                else
                                {   
                                    for (int x =1;x<g.NumberOfHitBoxes;x++)
                                    {
                                     if ((e.X>p["Hit"+x.ToString();].X)&&(e.X<p["Hit"+x.ToString();].X+hitw)&&(e.Y>p["Hit"+x.ToString();].Y)&&(e.Y<p["Hit"+x.ToString();].Y+hitw)){hitbox(c,p["Hit"+x.ToString();].X,p["Hit"+x.ToString();].Y,8);h=true;tb.Text = p.Type;hitok = p["Input"+x.ToString()+"Point"];}    
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!h){picture.Refresh();h=false;hitok = new Point(0,0);}
                            };
```

Simplified:

```
int x = 1;
int whatever = p["Hit"+x.ToString()].X;
```

Instead of this:

```
int whatever = p.Hit1.X;
```

Some bright intelligent person could maybe teach a dumbass like me a litle trick ??

Comment: Place your hitboxes into a list and do a `foreach` loop over that list.

Comment: I can only give you my usual Disclaimer: This looks like game development. GUI Desktop technologies are not the right way to develop games. Purely turnebasd single or hotseat multipalyer is the top, if do not go to decent with graphics. The old Windows Solitair is about the upper limits of what they support. For proper game development, you need something that has the Game Loop: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure

Comment: @dymanoid god idea, i´ll try that, but i need to get the point for "inputpoint 1,2 etc." i will see if i can create the hitbox from the connection point.

Comment: @Christopher It is not game related. I´m placing "Logic gates on the form and then i can draw connection lines between the in/outputs, but hitting the exact point is to hard, so i want to make hitboxes on all in/outputs. But you are right, this is not the right platform for game development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class

```
public class Phit
{
  public List<Point> HitBoxes { get; private set; }

  public Phit(List<Point> hitboxes)
  {
    HitBoxes = hitboxes;
  }
}
```

Initialize your class with the hitboxes.

```
List<Point> hitboxes = new List<Point>
{
    new Point(1.2, 1.5),
    new Point(1.2, 3.0),
    new Point(1.2, 4.5)
};

Phit phit = new Phit(hitboxes);
```

The loop inside your MouseMove method.

```
foreach(Point p in phit.HitBoxes)
{
    if (e.X > p.X && e.X < p.X + hitw && e.Y > p.Y && e.Y < p.Y + hitw)
    {
        hitbox(c, p.X, p.Y, 8);
        h = true;
        tb.Text = $"X: {p.X} / Y: {p.Y}";
        hitok = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: good solution, but i´m going to have 500+ gates with 3-10 hitboxes each and with this solution i will have to run all points through on each mouse move. I don´t have enough experience to determen if that is not going to cause lag. nut i will try to make a hitbox class for each component.